# How to get SVG filters to work on Firefox as well?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters, glow

I used an SVG filter to make the top line glow in my CSS animation. It does work perfectly fine on Chrome but not in Firefox. 
I read that Firefox has a different way to read SVG filters so I might need to add a bit more code specifically for Firefox. I've tried several things but none of them worked though. 
Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Thank you to everyone in advance.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.a1 {
  filter: url(#filter1);
  animation: stroke_fill1 4s linear forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 850.100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 850.100;
}

@keyframes stroke_fill1 {
  0% {
    fill: black;
  }
  50% {
    fill: black;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    fill: rgb(0, 255, 216);
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.b1 {
  animation: stroke_fill2 4s linear forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 850.100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 850.100;
}

@keyframes stroke_fill2 {
  0% {
    fill: black;
  }
  50% {
    fill: black;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    fill: rgb(149, 149, 149);
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <svg width="500px" height="400px" viewBox="75.000 80.7 350.769 80.092">

<defs>
       <filter id="filter1" y="-40%" height="180%">
<feGaussianBlur in="offOut" stdDeviation="5.5" result="blurOut"/>
           <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />

    </filter>
</defs>

  <path class="a1" stroke="#00E6CF" d=" M 151.5 255.5 L 448.5 255.5 C 455.399 255.5 461 261.101 461 268 L 461 268 C 461 274.899 455.399 280.5 448.5 280.5 L 151.5 280.5 C 144.601 280.5 139 274.899 139 268 L 139 268 C 139 261.101 144.601 255.5 151.5 255.5 Z " transform="translate(-60.5 -173.5)" stroke-miterlimit="10" filter="url(#filter1)" />

  <path class="b1" stroke="rgb(149, 149, 149)" d=" M 151.5 319.5 L 448.5 319.5 C 455.399 319.5 461 325.101 461 332 L 461 332 C 461 338.899 455.399 344.5 448.5 344.5 L 151.5 344.5 C 144.601 344.5 139 338.899 139 332 L 139 332 C 139 325.101 144.601 319.5 151.5 319.5 Z " transform="translate(-60.5 -173.5)" stroke-miterlimit="10" />


</svg>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson , thanks for your reply, tbh I'm not too familiar with the svg filters, I was playing around and managed to get the glow effect somehow. If there's a better way to do it, please do enlighten me. It's just a glow effect on the top line that I need.

Comment: the filters need to form a chain, if you have in="xxx" then there must be another filter with result="xxx" otherwise the chain is invalid and it doesn't work.

Comment: @RobertLongson I've just solved it by correcting it the way you suggested and deleting a few things. How can I give you the best answer? The new working filter is the following one:
       <filter id="filter1" y="-40%" height="180%"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5.5" result="blurOut"/>
<feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal"/>
    </filter>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to @RobertLongson I reviewed my code and I realised there was useless stuff as well as wrong syntax here and there.
Here is the working one. Thank you again.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.a1 {
  filter: url(#filter1);
  animation: stroke_fill1 4s linear forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 850.100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 850.100;
}

@keyframes stroke_fill1 {
  0% {
    fill: black;
  }
  50% {
    fill: black;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    fill: rgb(0, 255, 216);
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.b1 {
  animation: stroke_fill2 4s linear forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 850.100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 850.100;
}

@keyframes stroke_fill2 {
  0% {
    fill: black;
  }
  50% {
    fill: black;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    fill: rgb(149, 149, 149);
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <svg width="500px" height="400px" viewBox="75.000 80.7 350.769 80.092">

<defs>
   <filter id="filter1" y="-40%" height="180%">
       <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5.5" result="blurOut"/>
       <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal"/>

    </filter>
</defs>

  <path class="a1" stroke="#00E6CF" d=" M 151.5 255.5 L 448.5 255.5 C 455.399 255.5 461 261.101 461 268 L 461 268 C 461 274.899 455.399 280.5 448.5 280.5 L 151.5 280.5 C 144.601 280.5 139 274.899 139 268 L 139 268 C 139 261.101 144.601 255.5 151.5 255.5 Z " transform="translate(-60.5 -173.5)" stroke-miterlimit="10" filter="url(#filter1)" />

  <path class="b1" stroke="rgb(149, 149, 149)" d=" M 151.5 319.5 L 448.5 319.5 C 455.399 319.5 461 325.101 461 332 L 461 332 C 461 338.899 455.399 344.5 448.5 344.5 L 151.5 344.5 C 144.601 344.5 139 338.899 139 332 L 139 332 C 139 325.101 144.601 319.5 151.5 319.5 Z " transform="translate(-60.5 -173.5)" stroke-miterlimit="10" />


</svg>

</body>
```